# What kind of edm genres specifically did Delia Derbyshire help pioneer?

Tags: electronic-music

Ive read quite a lot (on the internet) about how she was a amazing producer (composer/dj) of her era and was wondering what specific genres did she pioneer her wikipedia page says musique concrete and ive read on some pages that she makes songs that are also very house but what are the specific genres that she pioneered? 
Is it just musique concrete and house or are there also other edm genres that she pioneered and what are they?

Answer (score 4):

The only real answer to this question is "all of them."  [At the time she was active](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXnmSgaeGAI), in the early sixties, there were no separate subgenres --or really, even any main genre.  Electronica was still considered experimental, futuristic, novelty music --not something you would hear on the radio, or at a club. The creation of EDM as a viable genre was still at least a decade in the future at that time.

She wasn't a DJ --at the time, DJs just played records, they didn't do any live remixing --nor were her songs released to radio. She worked behind the scenes. But her biggest innovation was probably the integration of a funky, pop-influenced sensibility into the nerdy, abstract world of electronica.  Her music was thus perfectly suited for the introduction of a dance beat.  In that sense, all of EDM owes her a debt.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CM8uBGANASc